# Apex Oracle : How to open a public page using a different session?

Tags: oracle, oracle-apex

I have a public Apex app and I need a specific page to open in a different session. Not use the same session as the rest of the application.

Basically, I have in Chrome

- Tab1 : Page A which requires authentication
- Tab2 : Page B which is public

I need both pages to run in two different sessions.

At Page B level, I set **"Rejoin Sessions"** to **Disabled**

Now when I run the application, Page B opens in a new tab with a new session as expected, however, it kills the session of Page A and I'm redirected to login.

I'm using an Authentication Scheme with custumized session sharing:

[image]

Does anyone know how to solve that please ?

Thanks
Cheers,

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The reason it kills your session from page A is because, on the client side, sessions are implemented using cookies. Both page A and page B are trying to use the same session cookie, with different session IDs, so whichever one writes to it more recently kills the other one.

If you view your cookies using your browser's F12 developer tools, you should see one like this:

```
Name                  Value                          Domain          Path
ORA_WWV_APP_115305    ORA_WWV_FMN08hWNhlkjRDOIU_y    yoursite.com    /pls/apex    (etc)
```

This is the session cookie for APP ID 115305, and the browser will send it along with every HTTP request to `yoursite.com/pls/apex`. Apex uses the `Value` to verify that you are allowed to have access to the session specified by the ID in your URL. If you modify either the cookie or the URL's session ID, your session is lost and Apex creates a new one for you.

So the `Name + Domain + Path` forms a sort of unique key here. You can only have one session for each unique Name + Domain + Path cookie.

**I think the easiest solution here is to put your public page B in a separate Apex App**. That way it'll have its own session cookie with a different Name.

(This is how the Oracle App Builder, which is also an Apex App, can have a separate session going at the same time without killing your app's session. Its cookies use a Name like `ORA_WWV_USER_9872`)

The alternatives are to use a different Domain or Path for page B, but that's trickier.

It looks like you've set up a custom Authentication Scheme, so I think your cookie would look like:

```
Name                  Value                          Domain          Path
SESSIONCOOKIE         ORA_WWV_FMN08hWNhlkjRDOIU_y    yoursite.com    /    (etc)
```

But you're still using the same Authentication Scheme (and the same cookie) for both page A and page B, so they can't have separate sessions. This would be an instance where it might be nice if Oracle supported using a separate Authentication Scheme for each page, but they don't. This is what separate apps are for.